# Array of time datatype elements

Tags: php, restler

What is the correct way to define the validation for array of time datatype elements?

Should be:

`@param array $arrayTime The time elements array {@type time}`

But then there is no way to pass the validators. No matter the input values, the best I can get is:

```
"Bad Request: invalid value specified for `arrayTime[0]`"
```

Comment: How you store time? As timestamp or in seconds?

Comment: I store them as

`time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ]`

As described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html)

But the issue is that the validators do not work correctly in this case. The input data can not even reach the function.

Comment: Ok, but what value you give to variable?

Comment: @Arthur That is the interesting part, that no matter the input data you always get an error. You can try with any strings integers, whatever. I guess in the validation path there are mutually exclusive condition like `is_numeric($param) and strpos(':',$param)>0`. So no matter the input data the validation always fail.

Comment: @AntoanMilkov You could have saved some time for all of us by letting us know that you are sending strings in `12:00:00` format. You can use  {@type string} and validate in your api method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

We have just added two types `time`(`time24`) and `time12` for this purpose

Download the latest Restler3 RC4 to get this functionality

```
/**
 * Array of times
 *
 * @param array $times {@from body}{@type time}
 */
function postTimes(array $times)
{
    return $times;
}
```

We have just added this to our Type test as well

Try it on the [explorer](http://restler3.luracast.com/tests/param/explorer/index.html#!/type/createTimes_post)

Comment: What I need to receive and if possibly validate is array of strings representing the time in 24h format from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00, like:
`['12:00:00', '11:00:00']`
Array of timestamps will not do the job in this case.

Comment: Timestamp will be 24h format. And if you want to record only hours, You can do it too.